# How to read 2 files and print matched pattern?

Tags: linux, perl

I am trying to read 2 files and trying to print matched pattern in both files.
It is not working. Can someone point me where I am doing wrong?

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 open (FILE1, 'Dimension.csv');
 my @dim=<FILE1>;
 close (FILE1);

 open (FILE2, 'SamsClub.dimension_refs.xml');
 my @xml=<FILE2>;
 close (FILE2);

 for(my $i;$i<@dim;$i++){
  for(my $j;$j<@xml;$j++){
   if($xml[$j] =~ m/$dim[$i]/) {
    print "Match found $xml[$j]";
   }
   }
 }
```

Note: FILE1 is csv file, FILE2 is xml file.

csv sample file

```
abc
defe
bald
```

xml sample file

```
<tem name="abc" version="2"/>
```

Comment: show us a fragment of both files. But if one file is a CSV and the other one is a XML, you need a more elabored script to compare the fields

Comment: The elements of `@dim` include the newlines. You probably don't want them when you're matching, so you need to chomp them all.

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
chomp @dim;
```

before the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually i tried with chomp too but it didn't work. After debugging I came to know that csv file contains control M's too. So after chomp, after removing control M's it worked.

Answer (score 3):

When you reading the files into arrays, they contains the `\n` character too. So, your `$dim[0]` contains `abc\n` and therefore doesn't match.

Someone sure will post more elegant solution, but you you can try:

```
my @dim = map { chomp; $_} <FILE1>;
```

Comment: `chomp` returns total character removed from the parameter list. Should be `map {chomp; $_} <FILE1>` here.

Comment: Yes, of course! Thank you. Corrected. / @Bramar 's solution is nicer anyway :)/